# Image slider with react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a image slider with react but can not figure out how to update the image when clicking a button that should update the images within an array.

```
import Volleyball from '../../assets/images/volleyball.jpg'
import Gaming from '../../assets/images/gaming.jpg'
import Coding from '../../assets/images/coding.jpg'

const ImageGallary = () => {

  let imgArray = [Volleyball, Gaming, Coding];
  const [images, setImages] = useState([...imgArray])


  const prevImage = () => {

  }

return (

 <div className={classes.gallary}>
     <div className={classes.direction}>
         <button className={classes.leftArrow} onClick={prevImage}>Left</button>
         <button className={classes.rightArrow} >Right</button>
     </div>
     <div className={classes.images}>
        {images.map((a, i) => {
            return <img className={classes.image} src={a} alt="" key={i} />
         })}
     </div>

 </div>

)
```

Answer (score 1):

just a simple way to change your image only update index and show,

```
import Volleyball from '../../assets/images/volleyball.jpg'
    import Gaming from '../../assets/images/gaming.jpg'
    import Coding from '../../assets/images/coding.jpg'

    const ImageGallary = () => {

      let imgArray = [Volleyball, Gaming, Coding];
     this.state={
    images:[...],
    currentShow:0
    }

      const prevImage = (conditon) => {
    const {images,currentShow}=this.state
       if(conditon){
    if(currentShow >= images.length){
    this.setState({currentShow:0})
    }esle{
    this.setState({currentShow:currentShow+1})
    }
       }else{
    if(currentShow < 0){
    this.setState({currentShow:images.length})
    }esle{
    this.setState({currentShow:currentShow-1})
    }
        }
      }

    return (

     <div className={classes.gallary}>
         <div className={classes.direction}>
             <button className={classes.leftArrow} onClick={()=>this.prevImage(false)}>Left</button>
             <button className={classes.rightArrow} onClick={()=>this.prevImage(true)} >Right</button>
         </div>
         <div className={classes.images}>
          <img className={classes.image} src={images[currentShow]} alt="" key={currentShow} />
         </div>

     </div>

    )
```

Comment: This works but I want all the images to be displayed in a row and change position with the next image in the array

Comment: yes this possible and easy , can you please share screenshot or sketch ,to clearly understand what you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this.

```js
import Volleyball from '../../assets/images/volleyball.jpg'
import Gaming from '../../assets/images/gaming.jpg'
import Coding from '../../assets/images/coding.jpg'

const imagesToDisplay = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src: Volleyball,
    alt: "Volleyball",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    src: Gaming,
    alt: "Gaming",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    src: Coding,
    alt: "Coding",
  }
]

const ImageGallary = () => {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(imagesToDisplay[0]);

  const handlePrevImage = () => {
    const prevImage = imagesToDisplay.find(image => image.id === (currentImage.id - 1));
    if (prevImage && prevImage.length) {
      setCurrentImage(prevImage[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleNextImage = () => {
    const nextImage = imagesToDisplay.find(image => image.id === (currentImage.id + 1));
    if (nextImage && nextImage.length) {
      setCurrentImage(nextImage[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.gallary}>
        <div className={classes.direction}>
            <button className={classes.leftArrow} onClick={handlePrevImage}>Left</button>
            <button className={classes.rightArrow} onClick={handleNextImage} >Right</button>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.images}>
          <img className={classes.image} src={currentImage.src} alt={currentImage.alt}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```